# How to create field with information from another field

Tags: django, signals

I have model and i have foreign key to another model and in that model i have `company_name` and i'm looking for way to create custom_id with some letters and then add company name into that id
it should look like this:

```
123456GOOGLE

OR

123456AMAZON
```

I tried to use signals but thats not what i need so how can i solve that?

models.py

```
class CompanyUserPhysicalCard(models.Model):
    card = models.ForeignKey(Cards, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='company_physical_user_cards')
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name='компания')
    custom_id = models.CharField(max_length=7, unique=True, default=company_card_code, editable=False, null=True,
                                 blank=True)
```

with that function i've got an error

```
 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'company_name'
```

```
def company_card_code(company):
    letters = '01234567890QLUBOK'
    result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(9)) + str(company.company_name)

    return result_str
```

Comment: You are getting this error because you are causing a recursion when you are updating the same model which was triggering the signal, and this update causing the signal to be triggered again. I feel using signals in this case is not correct. You can put this piece of code in either Model's save method, or in form's save method, and so on.

Comment: Please *don't* use signals: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html Exactly one of the (very) many reasons why you should not use signals... is because it makes code flow unpredictable and hence can result in infinite recursion.

Comment: The main problem why i think i need signals its bcs i need to update field automatically insta after creation

Comment: @Zesshi: no the main reason is that your `post_save` calls `instance.save()` which will trigger another signal and thus another save, and thus another signal run, etc. It actually shows quite nicely what the problem is with signals: that the function can trigger signals again and thus get stuck in endless recursion.

Comment: So how can i solve that problem? Bcs my field custom_id should have name of foreign key but thats possible only after creation

Comment: @Zesshi: I think it makes more sense to explain *what* you want to do (share the models and the use case). Likely it will be more convenient than fixing the signals, which will often only introduce more problems.

Comment: I've changed my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise to calculate the name on-demand, like:

```
from random import choices


class CompanyUserPhysicalCard(models.Model):
    def company_card_code(self):
        letters = '01234567890QLUBOK'
        return ''.join(choices(letters, k=6))

    card = models.ForeignKey(
        Cards,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='company_physical_user_cards',
    )
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name='компания'
    )
    _custom_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=6, default=company_card_code, editable=False, blank=True
    )

    @property
    def custom_id(self):
        return f'{self._custom_id}{self.company.company_name}'
```

We thus generate the code prefix, and when we need it, we append the company name.

If the company later changes its name, for example `'Facebook'` to `'Meta'`, without having to alter the table, it will also change the `custom_id`.

You can filter by concatenating with [**`Concat`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#concat), for example:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

CompanyUserPhysicalCard.objects.alias(
    custom_id=Concat('_custom_id', 'company__company_name')
).filter(custom_id='123456GOOGLE')
```